# How to run a local exe in a powershell script thats been packaged as an exe

Tags: windows, powershell, exe

So I created a script in Powershell, packaged it as an exe, and now when I need to run adb commands inside powershell I can't seem to reference the full path of adb. I used the below to create the directory but when I try to call adb (located in the platform-tools folder next to my script), it won't run. Instead I see some temporary directory that isn't where my actual exe and platform-tools folder is located.

How do I get the working folder of the script so I can execute adb relative to the platform-tools folder?

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
Write-host "My directory is $dir"

& $dir\platform-tools\adb connect $ipaddress
```

Here is what I eventually decided to go with for anybody else out there looking as well.

```
Split-Path (Resolve-Path $myInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
```

Comment: This depends on the way you used to create your exe

Comment: You're probably better off setting an environmental variable for the path on the host system, then using that environmental variable in your script.

Comment: I already packed the powershell script into an exe with powershellGUI. How do I know what the path is that an exe runs from? That way I can do my file manipulation. Right now I can't execute commands in my powershell as an exe because its operating from a temporary memory location when I use cwd. I need to be able to use this script on any Windows PC without specifying the exact adb commands I've put in the same folder as the script itself.